# Retrieve hotel rates from Booking.com search result page

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, web-scraping, http-post

I'm trying to retrieve hotel prices at Booking.com search result page from my Google Apps Script like the code below, but somehow it seems only to return the top page of Booking.com.

```
  var formData = {
    'ss':'Kyoto',
    'checkin_year':'2018',
    'checkin_month':'10',
    'checkin_monthday':'1',
    'checkout_year':'2018',
    'checkout_month':'10',
    'checkout_monthday':'2',
    'no_rooms':'1',
    'group_adults':'1'
  }

  var options = {
    'method' : 'post',
    'payload' : formData
  }

  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch('http://booking.com/searchresults.ja.html', options);
  var html = response.getContentText('UTF-8');
  Logger.log(html);
```

When I hit the browser with the address like below, that works. I'd like to web-scrape this results.

https://www.booking.com/searchresults.ja.html?ss=kyoto&checkin_year=2018&checkin_month=10&checkin_monthday=1&checkout_year=2018&checkout_month=10&checkout_monthday=2&no_rooms=1&group_adults=1&group_children=0

Could anyone help me move forward? Any comment would be appreciated!

Comment: You have set the method to `post` however if you go to the page by that link you use the `get` method. So maybe you should use `method: get`

Comment: assure you don't need to pass some cookies along with request, in order to have same response...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `POST` is wrong because `POST` will attach your options to the message body and not the URL. Using `GET` will attach your options to the URL as query-strings `?foo=bar`.

So, try changing the `method` in your `options` to `get`, so that the options get attached to the URL:

```
var options = {
    'method' : 'get',
    'payload' : formData
}
```

Comment: Thanks Martin, you were right! I mixed up POST with GET. Now GET returns the desired contents :))

Comment: Awesome! Glad you got it working. Don't forget to accept the answer if it helped you. Good luck with the rest of your project :)

Answer (score -3):

You have to make the response into json format

```
let url = 'https://example.com';

fetch(url)
.then(res => res.json())
.then((out) => {
  console.log('Checkout this JSON! ', out);
})
.catch(err => { throw err });
```

Comment: Changing the data type to JSON will not magically change the desired content into what the OP wants - read the question again! The OP wants to scrape HTML from an external source but is having difficulties loading the correct data source.

Comment: This answer is not applicable to Google Apps Script. There is no browser context, or support for `Promise`s or `let`.